# How do you subtract a value from the existing value in a field in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I thought I had a simple update statement:

Update LotDestination Set Quantity = Quantity - 2 where Lot = '9002ex'

Quantity is a field type of Number.

No matter what value is in Quantity, it always is 0 after running this query.

Is this an MS Access syntax issue, as I thought this was a pretty standard way to do things in other db platforms?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the statement, so maybe there's an issue with the data?

Comment: What happens when you do a `SELECT Quantity - 2  FROM LotDestination WHERE Lot = '9002ex'`

Comment: ChrisS asks a good question. Always test an update statement with a SELECT first.

Comment: did the select statement as you suggested and it caused me to discover an error totally unrelated.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following code and it works perfectly:

```
Public Sub UpdateQuantity()

Dim SQL As String
SQL = "UPDATE LotDestination SET LotDestination.Quantity = LotDestination.Quantity-2 WHERE LotDestination.Lot='9002ex'"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```